# USB/HID Commands to enable/disable a Symbol barcode scanner

Tags: python, barcode-scanner, symbols, hid

I have a Python application that is able to read scan data using https://github.com/trezor/cython-hidapi 
The problem is I have no idea what the HID commands are to enable/disable the scanner.  I think this might be generic across most scanning devices, but hunting for those commands and I have come up empty. Thanks.

Comment: If you can't find it under [here](http://www.usb.org/developers/docs/) then it's not generic.

Comment: http://www.usb.org/developers/hidpage/pos1_02.pdf

Comment: Why do you want to tell the scanner to disable itself? Just stop using it. Close the port if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the scanner you are going to use is Symbol LS2208, but this scanner's USB HID keyboard emulation mode does not have a command/response interface to control something(including Enable/Disable).
[LS2208 Reference Guide](https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra_new_ia/en-us/manuals/barcode-scanners/ls2208-product-reference-guide-v2-0-en-us.pdf)

If you want to control the scanner Enable/Disable, you need to use mode settings other than USB HID Keyboard, and the corresponding device driver/library.
[LS2208 Materials](https://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/scanners/general-purpose-scanners/ls2208.html)

If the scanner is Zebra's DS2278 or DS8108 you can control it with the HID POS interface commented by @Michael Doubez.
Also, many Honeywell scanners support this mode.
In this page [Supported Point of Service Peripherals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/pos-device-support), what is described as HID POS Scanner in the Mode field corresponds.

Comment: I see there is a "Prevent Read of Barcodes" command, but from that document I don't have a clue how to construct the byte array to get that to happen.

Comment: Since SDK and documents are posted on [LS2208 Materials page](https://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/scanners/general-purpose-scanners/ls2208.html), please get the information from there.
If you do not find it there, please [contact technical support](https://www.zebra.com/us/en/about-zebra/contact-zebra/contact-tech-support.html).